# show popup on click

Tags: html, json, fusion

i am using fusion chart want to show popup on click of bar of fusion bar-chart please help me i am using json method to generate chart
here is html :

```
<div id="chartContainerscoreConfidence" class="testseries-report-charts">
</div>
```

here is json code 
:

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        "type": "StackedColumn2DLine",
        "renderAt": "chartContainerscoreConfidence",
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "300",
        "dataFormat": "json",
        "dataSource": {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Time Taken",
                "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
                "plotgradientcolor": "",
                "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
                "showplotborder": "0",
                "divlinecolor": "CCCCCC",
                "showvalues": "0",
                "showcanvasborder": "0",
                "pyaxisname": "Question No",
                "syaxisname": "Time Taken (in minutes)",
                "numberprefix": "",
                "labeldisplay": "STAGGER",
                "slantlabels": "1",
                "canvasborderalpha": "0",
                "legendshadow": "0",
                "legendborderalpha": "0",
                "showborder": "0"
            },
            "categories": [
        {
            "category": [
                {
                    "label": "1"

                },
                {
                    "label": "2"

                },
                {
                    "label": "3"
                },
                {
                    "label": "4"
                },
                {
                    "label": "5"
                },
                {
                    "label": "6"
                },
                {
                    "label": "7"
                },
                {
                    "label": "8"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
            "dataset": [
        {
            "seriesname": "Time taken by you",
            "color": "008ee4",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "3",
                    "link": " "
                },
                {
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "value": "3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seriesname": "time taken by average student",
            "parentyaxis": "S",
            "renderas": "Line",
            "color": "f8bd19",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "value": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
        }
    });
    revenueChart.render();
})
```

i can redirect on any url, but not able to open a popup using jquery

js fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/y3H2G/226/

Comment: please help me  i am stuck on the problem

Answer (score 0):

There're many plugins. if you use bootstrap you can use the boostrap' modal dialog or you can use [bpopup jquery plugin](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/), here a demonstration (i've updated your js fiddle) : http://jsfiddle.net/y3H2G/227/

Code:

```
<!-- Simple implementation of the Bar 2D chart -->
<div id="chartContainerscoreConfidence" class="testseries-report-charts">
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show popup" name="btn" onclick="$('#chartContainerscoreConfidence').bPopup();" />
```

Comment: thanks but i want the popup on click on any bar not any button :(

Answer (score 0):

wooo
got the solution after lots of effort 
i have added a class in all bars and calling a click event on click on any bar

```
$(window).load(function () {


           //$('#raphael-paper-149').addClass('hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh');
           $("#raphael-paper-149 g").attr("class", "clickbleClass");
           $('.clickbleClass').click(function(){
            alert('hi');
           });
        });
```